# unknown object type 0 at offset - all repo mirrors corrupted preventing filter-branch subdirectory-filter

Tags: git, corruption, git-filter-branch, git-fsck

### 1) Problem Description

I have several pack files saying `unknown object type 0 at offset`, and unlike 99% of posts on the web this isn't a local problem but appears in both remote and cloned repos.

### 2) What I want to do

How do I simply remove those invalid references so that I'm not blocked from doing other operations on the repo? Ultimately, I want to run a `git filter-branch --subdirectory` command to split my 9.2G repo into submodules, but it chokes on these invalid pack files (note: index-filter works).

### 3) Full error message

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter mydir HEAD

error: unknown object type 0 at offset 78171701 in /media/me/unmirrored/trash/git_filter_subdir_attempt.2020-06-21/me.git.cloned/.git/objects/pack/pack-35b37571b163f30d71a98002a7f6a30aaeeadbad.pack
fatal: packed object a30f803926d5e369b0bda4982dba89fa7127cabe (stored in /media/me/unmirrored/trash/git_filter_subdir_attempt.2020-06-21/me.git.cloned/.git/objects/pack/pack-35b37571b163f30d71a98002a7f6a30aaeeadbad.pack) is corrupt
Could not get the commits
```

I've also put the `git fsck --full` output here: https://pastebin.com/WCnArrCh

### 4) What I've tried

#### fetch again

Most solutions assume you have an uncorrupted remote copy. But all my copies are corrupt.

#### Delete the reference

(I will add the unsuccessful outcome response after reproducing)

```
git update-ref -d abc123
```

(https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#salvage)

#### git-repair

(I will add the unsuccessful outcome response after reproducing)

```
git-repair
git-repair --force
```

(http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/git-repair.1.html)

Comment: Where is your remote located ? can you copy (an actual file copy: `cp -r` or `scp -r` or ...) the remote repository to your local computer ?

Comment: I've already tried that. It is my personal git repo and the server is also corrupt.

Comment: Then you should run the "cleanup" actions on the bare repository. If you can : run them on a copy.

Comment: `git prune` and `git gc` gives me the same error as above.

Answer (score 4):

Oh.. many attempts..
We Can be try this:

## First Try:

Recreate index:

```
git co -f HEAD   # git checkout
rm .git/index
git reset
```

Check and repair a Git filesystem

```
git fsck --full --no-dangling
```

if first not sucess, continue.

## Second try:

This is very drastic, and you lost log history. Will preservate only last version into main branch.

1. Locate last version functional; (ex: commit0 1e89694)
2. Create a new branch for recover;
   `git branch commit0 1e89694;`
3. Push it;
   `git push --all`
4. Create workdirectory for recover;
   `cd /tmp; git clone --depth 1 git@git.tool.com:youproject/project.git -b commit0`
5. From here critical checkpoint.
6. Go into workdirectory with problem.
7. Remove directory .git
8. copy all content into workdirectory recovery;`rsync -vaRCHz . /tmp/project`
9. `git add .; git ci -m "Recover $(date)"; git push --all; git merge --ff master`   # ci: commit
10. Finish!

### Obs:

If you have very binaries into git repositories, maybe necessary other configurations suply. https://stackoverflow.com/a/541490/5132101, https://opensource.com/life/16/8/how-manage-binary-blobs-git-part-7 or Git Large File Storage (LFS)[https://git-lfs.github.com/]

Details about alias git into post http://brito.blog.incolume.com.br/2013/03/guia-rapido-de-comandos-git-lado-usuario.html

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this. I'm trying it out now.

Comment: 1) After `git reset` it says `fatal: unable to read tree`. Does that matter? 2) Is this any better than creating a new git repo and copying all the latest files across?

Comment: in new git you lost all memories your project. In second try lost only log history.

Comment: `git: 'co' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` is not a command

Comment: excuse-me i use alias. read this post: http://brito.blog.incolume.com.br/2013/03/guia-rapido-de-comandos-git-lado-usuario.html

Comment: In my case, with `git fsck --full --no-dangling` was enough.

Comment: @AaA `co` probably is an alias of `checkout`

Comment: @britodfbr I'm sorry but I don't read polish. I assume to enable aliases you have to do something special which is not available when you install git with default settings. would be nice to mention full command is checkout or just use the full command to make it clear